# i have try using the Latin-1 and encoding="utf8" but is not working

Tags: python, data-science

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-0ce17dd3e5b7> in <module>
      1 open_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
      2 from csv import reader
----> 3 read_file = reader(open_file, errors='ignore')
      4 dataset = list(read_file)
      5 dataset

TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: You can't ignore errors using `errors='ignore'`, read the error message. Here is the documentation for [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). Try deleting it and trying again.

Comment: [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) doesn't have an errors parameter

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are a few problems with the following code (which I assume is all of your code):

```
open_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(open_file, errors='ignore')
dataset = list(read_file)
```

Firstly, [a note on style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), it's often clearer to do your imports at the start:

```
from csv import reader
```

Secondly, you're not necessarily ever closing your file, just opening it, so instead try:

```
with open('AppleStore.csv') as open_file:
   read_file = reader(open_file)

dataset = list(read_file)
```

That way it'll close it once the file has been read.

Thirdly, note that I removed `errors='ignore'` because the [`reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function doesn't have an errors argument, so it doesn't understand what you mean.